# How to bind external domain to .NET Core 3.1 Kestrel self-hosted application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I have a simple .NET Core 3.1 self-hosted Kestrel application. After publishing to my server, it runs correctly at http://localhost:5000.

I want to access this application via a remote browser, so I changed the `Program.cs` as below:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    {
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(so =>
            {
                so.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5000); //==> This is OK
            });
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
    }   
}
```

Now the application is reachable from any remote browser via `http://IP:port` address. Instead of using IP:Port, however, I want to bind a domain URL (for example `www.XXXX.com`) to my application.

I use Cloudflare as my DNS and proxy server. Keep in mind that Cloudflare does not support port forwarding. Also, the Portzilla App in Cloudflare had no use for me.

What I have done so far is I’ve added a new IP (let’s say `112.250.22.33`) to the server, and tried to configure the application to listen on port 80 of this specific IP address:

```
webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(so =>
{
    so.Listen(IPAddress.Parse("112.250.22.33"), 80); //==> NOT OK
});
```

With this configuration, however, the application does not run at all—even if I run it in *Run as administrator* mode. Instead, it returns with this error:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
>             Unable to start Kestrel.
>       System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10013): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That looks right but binding to port 80 requires admin permissions. https://serverfault.com/questions/112795/how-to-run-a-server-on-port-80-as-a-normal-user-on-linux

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but looks like `80` port is holding by IIS. I disabled `DefaultWebSite` and could bind domain name to local Kestrel run.